# Em que consiste este 'vocabulário' de pronúncias e para que serve?

Tags: pronúncia

Eu realmente não consigo entender coisas como essas:

- /taʃi/
- /leytshi/
- /pódzhi/
- /pɔrtɐʃ/
- /portʊ/

Eu sei que é a pronúncia das palavras representada em texto, mas alguém poderia me explicar exatamente o que é isso? É importante para melhor entendimento da Língua Portuguesa?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

É o [IPA (International Phonetics Alphabet)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet).

A função dele, em poucas palavras, é servir como instrumento de como pronunciar uma determinada palavra num determinado idioma. Diferentemente do alfabeto ocidental tradicional, os termos expressos no IPA possuem apenas uma única forma correta de serem pronunciados.

É bastante útil para ensinar pronúncia a pessoas que estejam aprendendo uma outra língua.

[Este link possui os fonemas e a forma de pronunciá-los, com o áudio](http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds/ipa-chart-with-sounds/). Pode ser bastante útil.

Tendo isto, fica mais simples [entender este outro link aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_Portuguese), em que temos toda a tabela fonética da língua portuguesa.

Comment: +1 pelo link com áudio.

Comment: Oh obrigado! Vou checar agora.

Comment: Não é IPA, mas sim é uma transcrição fonética.

Answer (score 10):

Complementando a excelente resposta do Cigano, eu gostaria de adicionar que o Alfabeto Fonético Internacional ajuda também a mostrar a diferença de pronúncia de palavras entre diferentes regiões de um mesmo país, tornando possível distinguir sotaques de maneira clara e direta.

No caso específico das palavras que você menciona na sua pergunta, elas mostram a [Palatalização de /di/ e /ti/](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portugu%C3%AAs_brasileiro#Palataliza.C3.A7.C3.A3o_de_.2Fdi.2F_e_.2Fti.2F) que ocorre principalmente na região Sudeste do Brasil. Por exemplo, as palavras /leytshi/ e /pódzhi/ representam, respectivamente, as pronúncias mais comuns das palavra **leite** e **pode** naquela região.

O que acho interessante nas palavras que você listou, é que elas são pronunciadas de maneira bem diferente nas demais regiões do Brasil, mas quem tem esse sotaque (como eu) nem sempre tem consciência disso. Imagino que quem quer que tenha lhe indicado essa lista de palavras esteja tentando te mostrar uma pronúncia específica, através do uso do alfabeto fonético.

Comment: Aliás, acho que seria legal poder fazer um mapa fonético das variações dos sotaques pelo país, mas imagino também que seria um esforço enorme.

Comment: Existe um esforço deste tipo na Wikipédia: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portugu%C3%AAs_brasileiro#Dialetos_do_portugu.C3.AAs_brasileiro

Answer (score 7):

Você acertou; é "exatamente" "a pronúncia das palavras representada em texto." Outro nome para ela é "transcrição fonética".

É importante entender que há mais do que uma maneira de representar pronunciações, e que uma pronunciação pode ser representada com mais ou menos detalhe. Já os seus exemplos usam dois sistemas diferentes: o [Alfabeto fonético internacional](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto_fon%C3%A9tico_internacional) (AFI ou IPA, feito pelo [IPA](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/)):

> /taʃi/
>
> /pɔrtɐʃ/
>
> /portʊ/

e um outro sistema baseado numa mistura das ortografias de português e inglês:

> /leytshi/
>
> /pódzhi/

## Por que usar transcrições fonéticas?

Usar sistemas fonéticas para representar pronunciações permite:

- explicar a pronúncia duma palavra para alguém que não conhece a língua
- desambiguar uma palavra escrita duma forma que permite mais de que uma pronunciação na sua língua (por exemplo, o primeiro ⟨o⟩ em ⟨porto⟩)
- mostrar como uma palavra é pronunciada por um certo dialecto, sotaque, ou falador
- mostrar detalhes duma pronunciação (como nasalidade) que não são realçados numa outra transcrição.

Assim, uma transcrição fonética pode ajudar um aprendiz a aprender pronunciar uma palavra, ou um pesquisador de linguística a comunicar melhor os detalhes duma pronunciação.

## Diferentes representações fonéticas

Compare alguns exemplos de escrituras fonéticas. O som das letras ⟨ch⟩ em português pode ser representado com:

- [ch] ou [x] em sistemas fonéticos baseados em português
- [sh] em sistemas baseados em inglês
- [ʃ] no AFI/IPA, ou sistemas baseados nele
- [š] no sistema ["Americanist"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americanist_phonetic_notation) usado por alguns linguistas

O som das letras ⟨tch⟩ (ou ⟨t⟩ antes de ⟨i⟩ no Brasil) pode ser representado com:

- [tch] ou [tx] em sistemas fonéticos baseados em português
- [ch] em sistemas baseados em inglês
- [t͡ʃ] ou [tʃ] no AFI/IPA, ou sistemas baseados nele
- [č] no sistema Americanist

O som da letra ⟨j⟩ pode ser representado com:

- [j] em sistemas fonéticos baseados em português
- [zh] em sistemas baseados em inglês
- [ʒ] no AFI/IPA, ou sistemas baseados nele
- [ž] no sistema Americanist

O som da letra ⟨o⟩ [quando é mais "aberta"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vogal_posterior_semiaberta_arredondada), ⟨ó⟩, pode ser representado com:

- [ó] em sistemas fonéticos baseados em português
- [ɔ] no AFI/IPA, ou sistemas baseados nele

O som da letra ⟨o⟩ [quando é mais "fechada"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vogal_posterior_semifechada_arredondada), ⟨ô⟩, pode ser representado com:

- [ô] em sistemas fonéticos baseados em português
- [o] no AFI/IPA, ou sistemas baseados nele

Recomendo usar o AFI/IPA sempre que possível, porque é o sistema mais universal e entendido internacionalmente. Para mais informações sobre como o usar para o português, veja [esta tabela na Wikipédia em português](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:AFI_para_portugu%C3%AAs_e_galego), e [este artigo na Wikipédia em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology).

### Breve nota sobre fonética e fonologia

De acordo com o Associação Fonética Internacional, uma transcrição fonética deve ser escrito entre `[` `]`, e `/` `/` usado para as [fonemas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia) da palavra. (E seguindo o mesmo sistema, `⟨` `⟩` para ortografia.) Por exemplo, as fonemas /ti/ em português, dependente no dialecto ou sotaque, pode ser pronunciado [t͡ʃi] ou [ti].